# mysql query doesn't stop running

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables t1 and t2, which are pretty much the same except for about sixteen thousand records t1 has that t2 doesnt. I am trying to do a left join in order to get the records which only t1 has.

when I run the following it seems like it runs(I always stop it early since this isn't exactly what I need, but I always get back matching results):

```
select * from t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

but when I add the following condition

```
select * from t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.id is null
```

it never stops. There are about 435,000 records in one and 420,000 records in the other. 
I have also tried indexing both tables on the field I am matching to no avail.

Comment: Is `SELECT *` really necessary?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I changed to just one field and it still runs forever

Comment: It can't stop. And it won't stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about something like this:

```
select t1.id from t1 where t1.id not in (select t2.id from t2)
```

Comment: this works... is there something wrong with the one I posted ?